# Jmeter TruncatedChunkException, Service says clientAborted

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

So I've been trying to load test my service using Jmeter CLI tool. I'm currently running 100 iterations for 3 users.

I'm noticing an intermittent issue during a Download request. The response of this request is binary data and I'm using Save Response to File Sampler for the same.

After random number of iterations, the test fails, and I can see that in the report Jmeter shows me this error

```
Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException/Non HTTP response message: Truncated chunk (expected size: 65,536; actual size: 35,597)
```

In my Service logs, I see the following exception

```
ClientAbortException java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried the following

- looked at service profile in grafana. It is well within the limits
- Jmeter Download Request Response timeout set to 300s, normal download time is 7s
- Unchecked keep-alive, and using  HttpClient4 now

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're getting are mutually exclusive, JMeter is complaining that it's getting an incomplete response and "Service" is telling that JMeter breaks the connection.

I would recommend [enabling JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

and additionally [enable Java logging for SSL/TLS connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.debug=all
```

If you confirm that JMeter is prematurely ending the connections - follow recommendations from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) JMeter Wiki Page